# How to do "while fetch assoc" in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What is the equivilent make code igniter get and write all variables...

This is what I would usually do something like:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aTable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc) {
echo $row['someContent'];
}
```

How would I do this in codeigniter?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After running your query, using either `->query()` or the "active record" class' `->get()`, use the `result_array` method.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM aTable");

foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    echo $row['someContent'];
}
```

Docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter 3, a better approach to your case would be [unbuffered_row](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=unbuffered_row#CI_DB_result::unbuffered_row)

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM aTable");

while($row = $this->db->unbuffered_row('array')) {
    echo $row['someContent'];
}
```

**Note:** retrieving large sets from database with this method will be more efficient then @Rocket Hazmat version. This is because the data is retrieved row by row, while `$query->result_array` is storing everything in memory.